# Is ECA required for spouse education - Express Entry

Tags: canada, immigration, resident-permit

ECA is done for principal applicant (that is me).

Principal applicant would like to immigrate with family (spouse & daughter).

Does it require to perform ECA (Education credential evaluation) verification for spouse education credentials?

Comment: @MarkMayo  yes,  am asking. if spouse can just come along or if they need ECA as well?

Comment: @MarkMayo The Express Entry penalizes a candidate for having a spouse, BUT the spouse can earn some of the points back if they have post-secondary education, English and/or French language ability, etc.

Comment: @mkennedy Does Express Entry do not encourage including spouse for immigration process, despite the principal applicant is married? Because i have created express entry profile and included my spouse as part of immigration.I can modify the express entry profile, if i can clearly understand why express entry penalizes a candidate for including a spouse for immigration.

Comment: @mkennedy if i include my spouse education, i did not get points for that. If i apply without spouse, am getting "342" points, if i apply with spouse am getting "333" points(including spouse language skills).

Comment: Look in the CRS section B, spouse education counts up to ten points for a masters.

Comment: @mkennedy i entered bachelor education details for spouse education, but i did not get 8 points for that.May be, Because ECA is not done for spouse education as mentioned in this [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp) --"you are an Express Entry candidate (or their spouse or common-law partner coming with them to Canada) being considered for the Federal Skilled Trades Program or the Canadian Experience Class, and you want points for your foreign education."

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the answer is pretty much the same than to [your question about Quebec](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5849/quebec-skilled-worker-program-2015). The whole logic of the system is that instead of a fixed set of requirements that would put you either in or out, you need [as many points as possible to improve your chances](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/pool.asp). If you think you don't need the points, you can forgo it but it can only help.

The [page you found](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp) seems pretty clear to me:

> you are an Express Entry candidate (or their spouse or common-law partner coming with them to Canada) being considered for the Federal Skilled Trades Program or the Canadian Experience Class, and you want points for your foreign education.

That means that your spouse's education won't count without ECA but also that it's not *required* per se. In practice, costs permitting, you should try to submit as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need ECA verification for your spouse also. I've created my account and getting zero point for spouse education, even though she has Bachelor degree.

Comment: do you have any references?

Comment: Checkout http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp, look at "Designated organizations for ECAs".

I've used World Education Services for my Bachelor. I've uploaded my degree scan to my submission as well as contacting the university to send the transcript directly to WES. My ECA have a note for that as well.