# Quebec skilled worker program 2015

Tags: france, canada, immigration, resident-permit, french-citizens

I had been through the [newsletter](http://www.canadavisa.com/quebec-skilled-worker-immigration.html) about QSWP program that is yet to launch in month of April, 2015.

As per the selection factors given [here](http://www.canadavisa.com/quebec-skilled-worker-immigration.html), below is my score chart as single applicant,

```
Education: 12 points         -     Bachelor's && Master's in Computer Engineering
Area of training:   16 points    - Computer Engineering (Bach.)
experience:   8 points           - 10 years Exp as Software Engineer.
Age : 16 points                  - 35 years, 1 month
IELTS(GT): 4 points              - L-7.5, R-6.5, W-6.5, S-6.0
financial self sufficiency: 1  point
```

To qualify for a Quebec Selection Certificate, Skilled Worker applicants must score enough points under the Quebec Immigration selection system. A single applicant must score at least **49 points** based on the criteria.

This [faq](http://www.canadavisa.com/quebec-skilled-worker-faq.html) says:

> 5. If I don't speak French, can I still obtain a CSQ?
>
> Possibly. The selection is done on a points-based assessment. If you meet the selection points requirements without speaking French you may still be granted the CSQ. Fill out our online assessment forms to find out if you qualify.

My question:

As my above score chart shows **57 points** as single applicant, Is it still mandatory to learn **French** language to gain Quebec province certificate?

Comment: Have you investigated the [Federal Skilled Worker](http://www.canadavisa.com/canadian-skilled-worker-immigration.html) route? With scores like that you should qualify easily, and English skills count equally with French skills. That would get you the right work in Quebec just as much as the rest of Canada.

Comment: @DJClayworth fsw is thru express entry since jan 2015, am already part of this approach. But this approach needs a job offer to get selected.

Answer (score 3):

Quebec understandably tries to attract immigrants with a good command of French and incite other immigrants to learn the language but knowing it is not, as far as I know, a strict requirement. Rather, it provides (many) extra points in the selection grid, can in certain cases exempt you from some yearly quota, etc.

Because there are many points attributed to French language knowledge, it can also help some applicants get over the threshold, even if they don't get many points from education, experience or “adaptability” at the interview (some applicants from France get selected with a much lower education level than yours). But since you already have 57 points, my understanding is that it should not be an issue.

Comment: As per this [link](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/immigrate-settle/permanent-workers/official-immigration-application/requirements-programs/index.html) the selection factor is: `Does your professional profile (as well as your spouse’s, if applicable) allow you to easily adapt to the requirements and rapid development of the Québec labour market? ` Shall i prepare for french language(oral) before an interview? How much time gap would I get between submitting the QSWP application and interview date(if invited).

Comment: @overexchange The text merely seems to explain what's in the grid. Note that knowledge of French is described as “an asset” and, in the list of employability factors, it's listed together with English, which strongly suggest that it is not a *requirement*, especially for those who can speak English. As much as some in Quebec might wish to reduce their number, the truth is that there are many English speakers in Quebec and among recent immigrants. It just can't be forbidden completely.

Comment: So speaking only English makes it harder to qualify but is not disqualifying. Note that many immigrants (probably not through the skilled migrant program, however) speak neither French nor English so by knowing English you already have an advantage when it comes to adapting to the Quebec labour market.

Comment: Note that it is probably impractical to learn French to a level sufficient to get points through the test but you could still try to teach yourself a few basics and see if you like it. If you do get invited for an interview, it would show some goodwill and could benefit you.

Comment: shall I start preparing the application and documents for QSWP? Because i feel that, despite i donot know french, i have skills that are in shortage.

Comment: @overexchange Honestly, I have no idea. I looked into it because I was in contact with a potential employer in Québec but I have never done it myself and I can't predict how it will go. I would think that 57 points is not bad so you do stand a chance but I can't say more than that.